How to write ellipsis related equations in Isabelle
I am new to Isabelle. I would like some guidance on a particular problem I have encountered while using Isabelle. I intend to define a number p as follows
$p=m_1m_2m_3...m_n$
I don't know how to define it but I tried this and it didn't work.
assume p::nat where "$p=m_1...m_n$"
I also tried this
assume p::nat where "$p=m_1,...,m_n$"
How does one write an ellipsis equation in isabelle? Or must one use the product symbol $\prod$? What if I don't want to use the product symbol is there a way out?

Can you come up with a more concrete proposal that doesn't require us to guess the rule? Suppose $m_k = 2k+1$, would you like to write $p = 1\cdots(2n+1)$ to automatically get $(2n+1)!!$ or something like that?

@Trebor yes absolutely. Such an example is okay.

When writing code (e.g. Isabelle code) put backticks around the code (one backtick for inline code and three for code blocks).  It makes it easier to follow.
